# Picasso doesn't work when compiling with certain other libraries in build.gradle

Tags: android, picasso, build.gradle

I'm guessing this is not a Picasso bug but would love to know how to fix it.

When including a certain library (github.com/thatJavaNerd/JRAW) in my dependencies, Picasso stops working. I don't get an image and I don't get any callback besides onPrepareLoad.

If I just comment out the compile 'net.dean.jraw:JRAW:0.6.1' in my build.gradle dependencies Picasso works as expected.

The JRAW library works as expected by itself and with Picasso included.

I'm guessing it is some type of dependency conflict but I don't understand why JRAW would still work.

No error messages from anything.

Comment: When I build the jar for JRAW myself, then Picasso only breaks when I manually include OKHTTP in my dependencies, which I need for JRAW to work. Still confused.

Comment: Manually adding OkHttp jar and OkHttpUrlConnection jar instead of including them via gradle has fixed the problem. Would love to know why this happened.